# Use a default value of StrEnum when invalid string is passed to Pydantic model

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a pydantic model like this

```
class Foo(BaseModel):
  field_a: Status
```

where `Status` is

```
class Status(StrEnum):
  X: auto()
  Y: auto()
```

It works when I create a Foo with the string "X" or "Y" as the field (for ex `Foo(field_a="X")`).

But it fails with a `ValidationError` when I use something else like `Foo(field_a="srgsefaa")`. In this case, is it possible to make it not fail but default to the enum value `X` somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `root_validator` from Pydantic. In Pydantic V2, this will be the `model_validator`. Try this:

```
from enum import StrEnum, auto

from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator


class Status(StrEnum):
    X = auto()
    Y = auto()


class Foo(BaseModel):
    field_a: Status

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def validate(cls, values):
        if values["field_a"] != "x":
            values = {"field_a": "x"}
        return values


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(Foo(field_a="z"))
```

Note: I've replaced the colons in your `StrEnum` class with = signs.